# How do I clean up and unload a Unity WebGL canvas when changing page

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've got a problem on my web application when I am changing the current page after downloading and running a Unity `WebGL` game.

In fact, I know for sure that the game is running because I continuously hear the sounds when my player is dying.

Is there a way to delete all of the context when changing a web page? Could this be a kind of memory leak?

Edit 1: My web application is done with AngularJS / Material

Comment: This is Unity bug for sure. However, you can create a browser script to force unload everything that's loaded.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really know what is loaded by Unity. How do I manage to do that without unloading my own scripts ?

Comment: There are like 5-10 files generated by Unity, unload them all (YourBuildName.data, YourBuildName.html.mem, YourBuildName.js, etc.) Edit: I think the are in `Release` or `Debug` folder depending on a build

Comment: What do you mean by unloading them ? In the index.html file I clearly see that a unity script is loading the files but I am not having any access to tell Unity to unload this files.

Comment: @NikaKasradze: javascript doesn't have any direct way to remove non trivial resources. When something is loaded it usually stays that way.

Comment: dang, I'm just being pedantic in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple: load the WebGL unity in an `iframe`, this sandboxes the application.

When you're done with the unity app just remove the node of the `iframe` like:

```
var iframe=...;
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
```

And it and all of it's resources should be instantly unloaded.

You can't communicate with the Unity player directly when you're in an iframe but you still can pass messages to and from it with [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your solution looks pretty nice and is interreseting but as soon as I put my unity WebGL inside an iframe, it doesn't even look for loading ressources...

Comment: This should not happen, can you give some more info? Web development console logs, online demo with the issue etc?

Comment: Well, I answer to quick. In fact, with the raw `index.html` that Unity generates when you build your game, it's working (and the datas are unloaded without doing anything).
The thing is that I was trying to pass AngularJS values directly through the iframe. I think I have no other solution to use the old school GET method. Or is it possible to use postMessage to pass AngularJS data's ?

Comment: It should be possible, but if you plan on passing this data only on init, the best way is to use the hash portion of the url (the part after `#` char, ex: `http://example.com/path?search#hash`). This way it won't even be sent to the server while still being available in JavaScript with `location.hash`.

Comment: God thanks for you help. You helped me out a lot ! It's ok for me but if you think I need to clarify something for the others, please tell me before I accept your answer :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the clarification of the postMessage part?

Comment: I don't want to use iframe, is there any other solution available?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan, this is a 3 year old issue, but I haven't seen any other way to do this since then. Maybe look at Emscripten (that's what Unity uses to build on the browser) - perhaps there is a better way by now. Some details on [what unity does when loading](https://www.quora.com/Is-Unity-WebGL-for-2D-games-good-how-much-are-the-load-times-and-performance) may be a good start. But why not iframe?

Comment: Actually I don't know that second team will use it(iframe) or not and the second reason is that i don;t know how to test that "it's resources should be instantly unloaded"

Comment: You don't need to use `postMessage` if the iframe is from the same domain. You can call functions in the iframe directly `window.frames[0].window.functionInIframe` and you can look up and directly manipulate the iframe's DOM `window.frames[0].document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'red'`; If they are from different domains you'll get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Unity 2019.1 provided proper way to Quit the webgl and release the memory(although it has failed in my testing, maybe i am wrong, please let me know it really works or not) :

- C#: call Application.Quit()
- JS: call unityInstance.Quit(callback)

You can use JS version like this

```
unityInstance.Quit(function() {
    console.log("done!");
});
```

For more please check [Quit and memory cleanup](https://forum.unity.com/threads/quit-and-memory-cleanup.571210/)