# How to Unload unity WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am using unity webGL build and this is the way to initalize/load unity webgl in javascript.

```
 var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/WebGLDemo.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
```

but there is no way to unload the webgl. I can remove the canvas tag but the problem is that some resources are remains in the memory which are not garbage collected. additionally when i try to remove

```
function DeleteGame(){
            console.log("remove game");
            document.getElementById("gameContainer").remove();
            //gameInstance = null;
      }
```

then we are getting furstum error

> Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000,
>   0.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 0 0)

Is there any proper way available to unload the webgl?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738981/how-do-i-clean-up-and-unload-a-unity-webgl-canvas-when-changing-page

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I don't want to use iframe tag.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan it seems to work though and you asked `Is there any proper way available` .. is there a special reason why you don't want to use an iframe?

Comment: Do you think that iframe is the right way to do this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unity 2019 beta, unity provides a built-in method(C#/JavaScript) to unload [Unity WebGL and cleanup memory](https://forum.unity.com/threads/quit-and-memory-cleanup.571210/).

- C#: call Application.Quit()
- JS: call unityInstance.Quit(callback)

You can either use C# version or Javascript:

```
unityInstance.Quit(function() {
    console.log("done!");
});
unityInstance = null;
```

For more details check [unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/quit-and-memory-cleanup.571210/) and [unity bu](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/webgl-player-continues-to-run-after-webgl-content-is-removed-from-dom?_ga=2.183452590.906210300.1554092380-1368490717.1540035490)g.

*I have used this function in unity 2019.1.0 beta but i am not sure that its cleaup the memory  but it definitely close unit webgl application.*

Comment: Hi, It says unityInstance.Quit is not a function. I have correctly assigned the createUnityInstance function to unityInstance but It does not work

Answer (score 0):

Note that from Unity v2020.1 on, unityInstance.Quit() no longer takes a callback function, but is a Promise instead.  So you have to call it like this:

```
unityInstance.Quit().then(function() {
    console.log("done!");
});
unityInstance = null;
```