# Unload Unity WebGL Player on Web Page

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I am running a WebGL player on my website

So I have this single line of HTML

```
<div class="avatarcolumn" id="avatar"></div>
```

Then I use this JS

```
var avatar;

function Avatar(avatarOn) {
  UI.setNamedOption('avatarOn', avatarOn);
  var avatarContainer = document.getElementById('avatar');
  while (avatarContainer.firstChild) {
    avatarContainer.removeChild(avatarContainer.firstChild);
  }
  Avatar.prototype.avatarContainer = avatarContainer;
  if (avatarOn) {
    avatar = new AvatarUnity();
  } else {
    avatar = new AvatarNone();
  }
};
UI.toggleAvatar = function (element) {
  new Avatar(element.checked);
};

//
// class AvatarNone
// inherits from Avatar
//   Dummy avatar leaves empty space
//
function AvatarNone() {
};
AvatarNone.prototype = Object.create(Avatar.prototype);

function UnityProgress(gameObject, progress) {
  if (!gameObject.Module)
    return;
  if (!gameObject.logo) {
    gameObject.logo = document.createElement('div');
    gameObject.logo.className = 'logo ' + gameObject.Module.splashScreenStyle;
    gameObject.container.appendChild(gameObject.logo);
  }
  if (!gameObject.progress) {
    gameObject.progress = document.createElement('div');
    gameObject.progress.className = 'progress ' + gameObject.Module.splashScreenStyle;
    gameObject.progress.empty = document.createElement('div');
    gameObject.progress.empty.className = 'empty';
    gameObject.progress.appendChild(gameObject.progress.empty);
    gameObject.progress.full = document.createElement('div');
    gameObject.progress.full.className = 'full';
    gameObject.progress.appendChild(gameObject.progress.full);
    gameObject.container.appendChild(gameObject.progress);
  }
  gameObject.progress.full.style.width = (100 * progress) + '%';
  gameObject.progress.empty.style.width = (100 * (1 - progress)) + '%';
  if (progress == 1)
    gameObject.logo.style.display = gameObject.progress.style.display = 'none';
}

//
// class AvatarUnity
// inherits from Avatar
//   Creates a Unity avatar
//
function AvatarUnity() {
  this.avatarName = 'avatarname';
  this.gameName = 'avatar';
  this.gamePath = 'pathtofile/file.json';
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.id = this.gameName;
  this.avatarContainer.appendChild(node);
  this.gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate(this.gameName, this.gamePath, {
    onProgress: UnityProgress, Module: {
      onRuntimeInitialized: function () {
        UnityProgress(this.gameInstance, 'complete');
        window.setTimeout(RemovePreloader, 5000);

      },
    }
  });
};
AvatarUnity.prototype = Object.create(Avatar.prototype);
AvatarUnity.prototype.showEmotion = function (emotion) {
  this.gameInstance.SendMessage(this.avatarName, 'change', emotion);
};

function RemovePreloader() {
}
```

All of this works fine and the WebGL Player runs successfully.

However, the issue I am having is that I want to remove the player from the DOM.

To do this, I have been trying to use

```
jQuery('.avatarcolumn').attr('style', 'display:none');
```

And I have also tried using the AvatarNone function in the code above.

While both of these methods worked and removed the player, before it gets removed, I get a notification in Chrome with the following message.

**An exception has occurred, but exception handling has been disabled in this build. If you are the developer of this content, enable exceptions in your project WebGL player settings to be able to catch the exception or see the stack trace.**

Is there a way I can remove the WebGL Player without getting this error message? If not, then is it an issue with the way I'm trying to remove the player or is it an issue with the WebGL Player itself?

I have also noticed that at the time of the error I also get a message in my console saying the following but I'm not sure how relevant it is

**Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000, 4.870000) (Camera rect 0 0 0 0)**

Comment: did you try as it suggested and  build a debug version and see what the errors are?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223801/1819684