# Error when destroying unity webgl instance on Vue3

Tags: vue.js, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have a working Unity WebGL application integrated with Vue3. Every time I move to a different page, there is always an error:
[image]

I tried to call `unityInstace.Quit()` during onUnmount event in Vue3, and the error changes to:
[image]

I suspect there is an issue on destroying the unity instance. However, I looked at Unity WebGL docs, and there doesn't seems to be any guides on disposing the Unity WebGL instance.

Thanks!

Comment: you might find some solutions to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738981/how-do-i-clean-up-and-unload-a-unity-webgl-canvas-when-changing-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clean up and unload a Unity WebGL canvas when changing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738981/how-do-i-clean-up-and-unload-a-unity-webgl-canvas-when-changing-page)